# Excluding certain features from clustering in MapBox GL JS

Tags: javascript, mapbox, geojson, mapbox-gl-js

I have a data-source for which clustering is switched on:

```
map.addSource('MySource', { 'type': 'geojson', 'data': GeoJSON, 'buffer': 0, 'cluster': true, 'clusterRadius': 1 });
```

However, there are certain features that I do NOT want to be clustered under any circumstances.  I appreciate that I could move those features into a different un-clustered data-source, but it would be far easier for me if I could keep everything in one data source and simply mark some features to be not-clustered.

I was thinking that I could add a property for each feature like `cluster: false` and I was wondering if, using such a property, it's possible to exclude some features from clustering...?  Possibly using the `clusterProperties`?

Has anyone else managed to do this?

Comment: In your case I would use other property name, that´s normally used in [mapbox cluster example](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/cluster-html/). You can use any other property name for that purpose and exclude the features marked as false in the method `updateMarkers()`

Comment: Hi @jscastro - thanks for the hint.  Using "cluster" as a property name is a poor choice.  If I were to change it to something like `allowthisfeaturetobeclustered = true / false` then it shouldn't clash with any properties set by Mapbox - but do you have an example of how I could then use `updateMarkers()` or `clusterProperties` to prevent Mapbox from clustering those features?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe it's possible to achieve what you want. A separate `geojson` source is the way to go.

Comment: I was hoping you wouldn't say that, but I suspected that may be the answer.  Thanks, though - that I can't do it is helpful to know.